# How to get search results in the backend admin on a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I have a custom post type books and have many meta boxes for it...etc But in the backend, I am not able to search anything.

For example I try to search the custom post type id in the search field, it comes back with no results.

How can I add different search items into the search query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol, i was just having the same problem :P
Well, this plugin is working for me: Search Everything -> https://github.com/sproutventure/search-everything-wordpress-plugin/ or in wordpress plugin page, by name search everything